# How to manage publishing maven settings.xml with artifact repository, mirror and proxy details to CI servers?

Tags: repository, continuous-integration, maven

Is there an automated process I can rely on, as an organisation's artifact repository / proxy manager, to publish configuration updates to dependent continous integration servers and developers?

For instance, if for some reason, I have to create or move a repository / proxy URL, is there any way to update Jenkins or TeamCity or whichever CI servers are in use in my organisation?

(apart from sending emails to the server administrators, naturally)

At the moment I am carrying this out manually, so all CI servers and all developers need to edit their settings.xml files.

I imagine such integration would be easy if one organisation such as Atlassian created a CI server and repo proxy, but I don't think any organisation does, or is there another approach, based on file shares for instance?

I have seen one solution where the organisation bundled the settings.xml with the maven rpm package and rolled it out as an upgrade, but I'm hoping for something simpler.

Comment: Puppet, Chef, Ansible, ... But it sounds like you still have silos in your organization that are getting in the way.

Comment: Silos? Quite possibly. But regardless, can you expand on that, in an ideal scenario? e.g. what event, human or machine-based, would trigger such a publication / distribution? Could this be run on Windows as well - I guess it depends on which of puppet / chef / ansible I choose. (I'm thinking of developers workstations)